How to include base64-encoded PDF content in JSON-LD?
I'm working on a project where I need to include base64-encoded PDF content as part of a JSON-LD document. I have a basic structure for my JSON-LD, but I'm unsure how to properly format the "evidence" field to include the base64 data.
{
  "@context": {
    "alumniOf": {
      "@id": "http://schema.org/alumniOf",
      "@type": "xsd:string"
    },
    "evidence": {}
  },
  "alumniOf": {
    "@id": "https://www.example.com/"
  },
  "evidence": "JVBERi0xLjcKJ...<base64-encoded PDF content here>..."
}

Can someone provide guidance on how to properly format the evidence field to include base64-encoded PDF data?

A data URI (which includes the media type) would be more sensible, but as other comments have already explained — this is not an appropriate use case for embedding binary data as a string… serve the binary PDF resource at a separate URL and include a link to it.
